# Website for file sharing and easy command line access

Tags: linux, web-apps, ssh

i have to transfer some files to a remote linux system which has no gui

What I am planning to do is to upload files to a website and do a wget of it from command line.

Is there a file sharing web site which gives download friendly urls ?

Comment: Welcome on Software Recommendation, your answer looks like the beginning of a hight quality question. I suggest you to read [this meta post](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information) about question's quality requirement and then improve your question with more detail about your requirement (File formats, max file size, security or privacy needs, prices, ...)

Comment: Why an intermediate website? Maybe you rather describe what you want to achieve (something like "Software to exchange files", with the hint a web-service would do as well, and all the other criteria described in [this meta post](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/185)). I run multiple "headless" Linux machines which share files amongst each other. Believe me, that doesn't need an intermediate website.

Comment: This question does not contain enough information to answer it or does not meet our minimum quality requirements. For guidelines on what your question should contain please see [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336)

Comment: @Izzy There may be reasons to do this. If you have to use an ssh connection over multiple hops it may be easier to share using a website than to set up port forwarding (or something similar) and use scp. Also it may make sense if you need to transfer the files to multiple systems. It would be nice to have the reasons in the question though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/). You only need to install it on the sender side. Just upload them to your public folder. They will then be accessible at the URL

```
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/YOURUSERID/YOURFILENAME
```

The first part of the URL (up to your user id) is the same for all files you upload, so you can just store it in a variable and use it multiple times. The files' names are chosen by you, so you can easily give it short or rememberable names.

A huge advantage is that you can upload additional files without clicking through long dialogs or syncing new download URLS. You can also delete the files whenever you want, so that it is not available to anybody else later.

If you cannot install the client on the sender side (but have a reasonably modern graphical browser and a dropbox account) you can also upload via the Dropbox website.